# Postgres primary key default value nil in created model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using rails 4.2 & postgresql and I'm working on existing non rails DB. table schema is given below:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: customer
#
#  CustomerNo            :text             default("P'::text || nextval('sqcustomer_no"), not null, primary key
#  CustomerOperatorId    :string(8)
#  CustomerType          :integer
#  BrokerId              :string(250)
#  Address               :text
#  SalutationId          :integer
```

Issue is:

```
customer = Customer.create! #successfully created
customer.id #nil value
customer.CustomerNo #nil value
```

I'm using 2 extension `postgis,  plpgsql` and `Coutomer.count` increasing properly.

I tried `customer.reload` its give me error.

output of `customer` instance variable

```
#<Customer CustomerNo: "P'::text || nextval('sqcustomer_no", CustomerOperatorId: nil, CustomerType: nil, BrokerId: nil, Address: nil, SalutationId: nil>
```

any idea why I'm getting this?

Thanks
Neelesh

Comment: Anything here of use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975081/camelcase-instead-of-snake-case-in-rails-db

Comment: @DavidAldridge I did but not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, have you told Rails that the primary key column is CustomerNo, not id?

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :customer_no
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes I Did self.primary_key = 'CustomerNo'