# What Does The Term "Opinionated Deployment Task-Runner" mean?

Tags: javascript, deployment

I often hear or see the term "opinionated" used in relation to deployment task-runners. All the cool kids are saying it these days.

For example, someone might says - " I don't use that task-runner, it's way too opinionated. I prefer this other task-runner".

For example on the Yeoman about page - http://yeoman.io/whyyeoman.html

```
Yeoman is a robust and opinionated client-side stack...
```

Or here on bower http://bower.io/

```
Bower is a package manager for the web. It offers a generic, unopinionated solution to the problem of front-end package management...
```

Sometimes I see it referring to JavaScript, e.g "The markup is highly opinionated".

What does this actually mean? Is this a new "thing" or has it been used for a while in web development?

Also can it be used in labelling from-end development markup like HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery etc...

Comment: https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/what-does-opinionated-software-really-mean

Comment: [Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802050/what-is-opinionated-software) was asked, and answered 4 years ago, so I don't think it's new. FWIW, I came here looking for the same answer and just discovered this myself.